# Standalone - DosBox

Tags: windows, portable, dosbox

I hope that this question is ontopic here.

I am looking for a standalone version of DosBox to run under Windows 7 (64 bit). I found:

- http://www.pendriveapps.com/dosbox-dos-emulator/
- http://portableapps.com/apps/games/dosbox_portable

But it looks like you actually have to install this.

What I am looking for is something like a zip file that is just unpacked into a folder such that DosBox will work right away.

Comment: have you tried downloading from http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1

Comment: @Keltari: I don't see any zip file for Windows

Comment: it has to be installed, as it needs to be configured for each system.

Comment: @Keltari: Ok, so you are saying that there simply isn't a standalone version available?

Comment: dont think so.  the installer has to detect your hardware to determine hwo to do emulation.

Comment: @Keltari: Ok, thanks for the answer. I will leave the question up for a bit longer in case someone might know a way to do this, but delete it later in case not.

Comment: @Keltari: AFAIK DOSBox's installer does not modify its conf file according to the available hardware. In any case experienced DOSBox users will prefer to tweak their conf files to best match their hardware and desired game behaviour (yes, often per-game settings are required, which is why so many frontends exist that provide game profile creation/management).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the first link, but PortableApps' version is indeed portable. Their .PAF.EXE (PAF = Portable Application (Installer) File) is an "installer" that simply extracts the app to the destination you choose:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Here's what you end up with:

```
DOSBoxPortable\App
DOSBoxPortable\Data
DOSBoxPortable\Other
DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.exe
DOSBoxPortable\Help.html
DOSBoxPortable\App\AppInfo
DOSBoxPortable\App\DefaultData
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox
DOSBoxPortable\App\AppInfo\appicon.ico
DOSBoxPortable\App\AppInfo\appinfo.ini
DOSBoxPortable\App\AppInfo\installer.ini
DOSBoxPortable\App\AppInfo\appicon_128.png
DOSBoxPortable\App\AppInfo\appicon_16.png
DOSBoxPortable\App\AppInfo\appicon_32.png
DOSBoxPortable\App\DefaultData\settings
DOSBoxPortable\App\DefaultData\settings\dosbox.conf
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Documentation
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Video Codec
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\DOSBox 0.74 Options.bat
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Reset KeyMapper.bat
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Reset Options.bat
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Screenshots & Recordings.bat
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\SDL.dll
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\SDL_net.dll
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\DOSBox.exe
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\DOSBox 0.74 Manual.txt
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Documentation\AUTHORS.txt
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Documentation\COPYING.txt
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Documentation\INSTALL.txt
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Documentation\NEWS.txt
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Documentation\README.txt
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Documentation\THANKS.txt
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Video Codec\zmbv.dll
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Video Codec\zmbv.inf
DOSBoxPortable\App\DOSBox\Video Codec\Video Instructions.txt
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Help
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Help\images
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Help\images\favicon.ico
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Help\images\donation_button.png
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Help\images\help_background_footer.png
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Help\images\help_background_header.png
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Help\images\help_logo_top.png
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\DOSBoxPortable.ini
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\DOSBoxPortable.jpg
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\CheckForPlatformSplashDisable.nsh
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\ReadINIStrWithDefault.nsh
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\DOSBoxPortable.nsi
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\AppSource.txt
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\License.txt
DOSBoxPortable\Other\Source\Readme.txt
```

In general all of PortableApps' programs are structured the same way. At the top-level you have ***AppName*Portable.exe** (in this case **DOSBoxPortable.exe**), which acts as a "wrapper" for **App\*AppName*\*AppName*.exe** (in this case **App\DOSBox\DOSBox.exe**). I just confirmed and PortableApps' DOSBox Portable does not interfere with my installed DOSBox (with custom settings) in any way. In future if you want a ZIP archive instead of the .PAF.EXE you can simply ZIP up the entire extracted folder structure.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but thanks for the answer. I seems strange that they call it "installing" when people would want to use the portable version because they don't want to install.

Comment: Yes, "extracting" would be more apt terminology IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the windows installer, install it where you want.
After installing save the installed directory (copy or zip it somewhere else ) and uninstall dosbox.
After uninstalling just copy the formerly installed directory where you want.

Comment: Did you read the other answer?  Why would somebody want to do what you suggest if that other answer works?

Comment: Yes, I have read, a just didn't like the PA logo when I started dosbox.
Why would I use another program to do the work if can do it without any other mess in my OS.

Comment: “Why would I use another program to do the work if [I] can do it …?”  Why do people use computer programs to do anything (e.g., compute taxes, check spelling, send messages) that can be done without the computer?  Umm, …, less work?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Also, “download the Windows installer [and] install it” sounds like it has to be done with elevated privileges (does it?), and some people prefer to avoid that (hence, portable apps).

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Win32 Installer version from here https://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1
2. Change the executable extension to zip, for example, `DOSBox0.74-3-win32-installer.exe` to `DOSBox0.74-3-win32-installer.zip`
3. Unzip the content and that's it

Now you can run DOSBox.exe and start using it.